# Change Mozilla settings globally on internal network

Tags: ntlm, mozilla

We have a network in our company and I want to set network.automatic-ntlm-auth.allow-non-fqdn parameter to True in Mozilla FireFox for all clients,how can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Find the required registry setting, and push it out with Group Policy Preferences. Or search for a Firefox GPO administrative template that has the setting defined.

Comment: Mozilla Firefox does not use the registry for storing its configuration. It uses preferences files instead.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox doesn't really want to be managed this way, to be honest.

It may be possible to bodge a solution by using a lock file (a mozilla.cfg file, configured as per [this mozilla KB article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Locking_preferences)). You can then use a startup/login script in a GPO to push that setting out to all your machines.

However, I personally think this will not be a satisfactory solution in the end. Mozilla simply don't appear interested in creating a system that can be reasonably managed in an enterprise.

Answer (score 1):

[MozillaGPO project](https://mozillagpo.sourceforge.io/) provides mozilla [autoconfig.js](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MCD,_Mission_Control_Desktop_AKA_AutoConfig) module that allow managing mozilla software wia Group Policy.